# How to replace spaces between words with another word?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell G which stores random words like "Hello, How are you"
I want to replace all the spaces with %20 to make it
"Hello%20,%20How%20%are%20you"

How can i replace spaces with %20?

Thanks

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? REPLACE: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/replace-replaceb-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a SUBSTITUTE: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(G1; " "; "%20")
```

Comment: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971527223459&text=Hi,%20I%20want%20to%20enquire%20about%20LED Braket Without Tube%20having%20Product%20SKU:Tube%20& Braket

Comment: it replaces %20 for the first space but not for the second onwards

Comment: `=REGEXREPLACE(G1; "\s"; "%20")`

Comment: @PythonDev share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to change and run this:

```
Sub SpaceChanger()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(r.Value, " ") <> 0 Then
                r.Value = Replace(r.Value, " ", "%20")
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

*(using a macro will allow you to change the values "in place")*